# Can you use Windows 10 credentials as Authentication for a login page in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently making some web pages using .Net Core MVC 3.1.

In my project there are different views for different users: for example a beginner user can do some things and an advanced user can do other things etc...

So I've implemented a login system and I was asking myself if it was possible to use Windows credentials for the login --> if the user logs in with his local windows user credentials, he's going to be an advanced user.

I've looked this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

but I couldn't find anything helpful... also I coldn't understand much of its content.

Eventually I've created a new MVC project with Windows Authentication enabled in the creation page/menu, then without any modifications I've made it run but the web page asks me my Windows credentials first of anything else. Not the kind of behaviour I wished. Is it possible to move this behaviour to my login page?

Hope you guys could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When both Windows Authentication and anonymous access are enabled, use the [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] attributes. The [Authorize] attribute allows you to secure endpoints of the app which require authentication. The [AllowAnonymous] attribute overrides the [Authorize] attribute in apps that allow anonymous access.

E.g. `[AllowAnonymous] LivingRoomController` allow everyone. `[Authorize] BedroomController` will prompt for credentials.

Docs are pretty straightforward.

For the modern ASP.Net I strongly reccomend you to read this [authorization conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1.)